# Trying to show that $(2^{i_k} - 3^k)u - 3^{k-1} - \sum\limits_{s=1}^{k-2}3^{k-1-s}2^{i_s}$ is not equal to a power of $2$.

Tags: number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, collatz-conjecture

As I was thinking about the Collatz Conjecture, it occurred to me that it would be helpful to confirm that $(2^{i_k} - 3^k)u - 3^{k-1} - \sum\limits_{s=1}^{k-2}3^{k-1-s}2^{i_s}$ is not a power of $2$.

I thought that this would be straight forward to prove but I am unable to complete the argument.  Is there a straight forward way to show this or is this more difficult than it appears?

Let:

- $i_1, i_2, \dots, i_k$ be $k >3$ integers where:

$$i_k > i_{k-1} > i_{k-2} > \dots > i_2 > i_1 > 0$$

- $u$ be the minimum integer where:

$$(2^{i_k} - 3^k)u > 3^{k-1} + \sum\limits_{s=1}^{k-2}3^{k-1-s}2^{i_s}$$

Intuitively, I would assume that $(2^{i_k} - 3^k)u - 3^{k-1} - \sum\limits_{s=1}^{k-2}3^{k-1-s}2^{i_s}$ cannot be a power of $2$.

It would seem to me that a proof by contradiction should work where the first 4 steps might be:

(1)  Assume it is a power of $2$

(2)  $u$ must be odd since the sum must be even so that there exists $v$ with $u=2v+1$

(3)  $(2^{i_k} - 3^k)(2v+1) - 3^{k-1} - \sum\limits_{s=1}^{k-2}3^{k-1-s}2^{i_s} = 2v(2^{i_k} - 3^k) + 2^{i_k} - 3^{k-1}4 - \sum\limits_{s=1}^{k-2}3^{k-1-s}2^{i_s}$

(4)  Dividing by $2$ we have:

$$v(2^{i_k} - 3^k) + 2^{i_k-1} - 3^{k-1}2 - \sum\limits_{s=1}^{k-2}3^{k-1-s}2^{i_s-1}$$

At this point, the approach gets more complicated.  If $i_1 = 1$, then $v$ is even.  if $i_1 > 1$, then $v$ is odd.

I can see going through this process of breaking down $v$ into either $2w$ or $2w+1$ but I suspect that there is more standard and simpler way to prove that this sum is not a power of $2$.

Comment: Your expressions don't use $i_{k-1}$ anywhere. Is it possible the upper limit of your summations should be $k - 1$ instead of $k - 2$? Your question seems to be related to the Collatz conjecture and, as I recall, that is the upper limit used in the summation. Also, note you have a minor typo of $1_{1}$ instead of $i_{1}$ in your first bullet point.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Fixed the typo. Thanks.   $i_{k-1}$ is missing on purpose. If I can show that the sum is not a power of $2$, then I can show that $2^{i_{k-1}} > 2^{i_k-1}$ which goes against one of the assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. You're basically using $i_{k-1}$ as just a "spacer" between values so, FYI, here's an equivalent set of expressions without any unused value. Replace your first bullet point with: $j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_m$ be $m \gt 2$ integers where $j_m \gt j_{m-1} \gt \cdots j_{2} \gt j_{1} \gt 0$. Your second bullet point becomes: $u$ be the minimum integer where $(2^{j_m+1} - 3^{m+1})u \gt 3^{m}+\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}3^{m-s}2^{j_s}$. We have $k=m+1$, $i_{t} = j_{t}$ for $1 \le t \le k - 2$ and $i_{k} = j_{m} + 1$. This means $i_{k} \gt j_{m} \ge i_{k-1} \gt i_{k-2} = j_{m-1}$.

Comment: That's a good point.  I'll update the question.